# Wrong rest service is selected

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs, uritemplate

i have resource with two methods:

```
@GET
@Path("/{date}")
public Response getPartnerInteractionsByDate(
        @PathParam("partnerId") int partnerId,
        @PathParam("date") String date
);

@GET
@Path("/{interactionId}")
public Response getPartnerInteraction(
        @PathParam("partnerId") int partnerId,
        @PathParam("interactionId") int interactionId
);
```

how can I select one or another service? if I put "1" for interactionId, still the method with date gets executed.
I am using apache cxf 3.0.1. Thank you

Comment: Does `date` have a format? Maybe you could use a regex pattern instead of just string.

Comment: Please be much more specific. What URLs would you like to have be routed to which methods? Why do you have two path params in each but only one {} pattern in each?

Comment: @bmargulies You can have template expressions at the class level (for which we care not seeing :-). Maybe `{partnerId}` is in the class level `@Path`

Comment: @peeskillet yes the partnerId is on the class '@Path'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems. The first is that your Path must contain the PathParams you're binding. Second, your two paths are identical in that they both take 2 parameters of the same type (cxf has no way of knowing the difference between an int and a string containing an int).

Try something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{partnerId}/date/{date}")
public Response getPartnerInteractionsByDate(
        @PathParam("partnerId") int partnerId,
        @PathParam("date") String date
);


@GET
@Path("/{partnerId}/{interactionId})
public Response getPartnerInteraction(
        @PathParam("partnerId") int partnerId,
        @PathParam("interactionId") int interactionId
);
```

Comment: The first point is not completely valid as the `{partnerId}` can be contained in the class level `@Path` ;-)

Comment: yes, sory for missing that out from code, partnerId is binded at class level @Path

Comment: thank you, I redesigned the paths with "/date/" addition

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, your template expressions have ambiguous paths. After the three main sorting keys <sup>[**1**]</sup>, the path is still ambiguous. URIs don't know about types. Everything is the URI (and during URI matching) is a String. The template expression values will later get converted to our method parameter types (if it is a convertible type <sup>[**2**]</sup>).

That being said, a way you can disambiguate the two is by using regular expression for the template. For example

```
@Path("/{date: \\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}}")
public Response getPartnerInteractionsByDate

@Path("/{interactionId: \\d{10}}")
public Response getPartnerInteraction
```

This is assuming dates com in `MM-DD-YYYY` format and interaction ids are ten digits. This is just an example, but shows how you can make it work.

If there are absolutely no regex patterns that can match the URIs, then you will need to change the path (add a part to one of them) to disambiguate.

---

<sup>[**1**]</sup>

1. The primary key of the sort is the number of literal characters in the full URI
   matching pattern.
2. The secondary key of the sort is the number of template expressions embedded
   within the pattern
3. The tertiary key of the sort is the number of nondefault template expressions. A
   default template expression is one that does not define a regular expression

<sup>[**2**]</sup>

1. It is a primitive type. The `int`, `short`, `float`, `double`, `byte`, `char`, and `boolean` types all fit into this category.
2. It is a Java class that has a constructor with a single `String` parameter.
3. It is a Java class that has a `static` method named `valueOf()` that takes a single `String` argument and returns an instance of the class.
4. It is a `java.util.List<T>`, `java.util.Set<T>`, or `java.util.SortedSet<T>`,
   where `T` is a type that satisfies criteria 2 or 3 or is a `String`.

Comment: thank you i forgot about the patterns in path, good point! +1